# Finding and overriding a default code snippet within VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, automation, tabstop

I am currently exploring tabstops within snippets inside of VSCode. There is a situation where I'd like to issue a tabstop, but a default snippet is overtaking my action.

The following is the behavior that my snippet attempts to accomplish. To begin, my cursor is within the boundaries of an array [0,1,1], and I issue a tabstop to advance outside the array. However, when I do this, my data gets converted to this   <div 0,1,1="">, which is not what I want.

Here is the VSCode snippet that I've created:

```
        "prefix": "pat",
        "body": [
            "${1}: [$2],",
            ""
        ],
        "description": "pat"
    }
```

Comment: looks like Emmet has recognized a possible prefix, the tooltip should show this, so press Escape to terminate suggestion on this point and then press TAB

Comment: Emmet is recognizing a custom attribute (see https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#custom-attributes), so do what @rioV8 says .  You can exclude languages, like javascript, from emmet expansion in vscode's settings but you would lose it for the entire language.

Comment: The escape suggestion worked, thanks. I realized for my purposes that cmd+enter is a more straightforward way of working. I realized that I only wanted to tabstop outside of the array so that I could advance to the next line.